# Why are Mutants generally blue if they have a non-normal color?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, mutant

In the X-Men film series, many mutants (if not all) that have abnormal color as part of their mutation are blue.

For example Beast grows blue hair, Mystique has blue skin in her "natural" form, The Incredible Nightcrawler has blue skin, etc. Is it intentional that they all have blue? Am I missing an obvious example of this or the opposite? Above all, **why are they all blue?**

Comment: Counterexamples include Toad and Azazel

Comment: Isn't Toad normal color?

Comment: Toad: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/04/Ray_Park_as_Toad_%28comics%29.jpg

Ray Park's natural complexion: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/RayParkSpeakingFrontJun2011.jpg

Comment: Mystique and Nightcrawler are related. Maybe blue works best on green screens while being a weird skin tone.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Not confirmed in the film continuity.

Comment: https://wegotthiscovered.com/movies/scientist-explains-xmen-mutants-blue-skin/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/4gptl9/marvel_why_so_many_blue_muties/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Is that really the reason? I had written it off as too much biology.

Comment: Because they'd rather be blue over you, than happy with somebody else.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Neither link has anything substantive. In the movie universe, it basically likely boils down to there being three groups that account for most of the blue characters: the Kree (mainly in Agents of SHIELD), people related to Mystique (Nightcrawler, and Beast derived his "cure" from her, and people associated with Apocalypse (who might be the result of Kree meddling). Could also just be them being different since blue is so rare in the real world. Or, lastly, it worked well for the inkers.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots For Mystique and Nightcrawler, it doesn't matter if not confirmed in the films because it's not like they're just going to drastically change the colour in the films from the source material and result in unrecognizable characters.

Comment: This isn't really a movie question, since all the mentioned examples were all blue in the comics long before they appeared in films.

Comment: “Da ba dee da ba di… Da ba dee da ba di… Da ba dee da ba di—“

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a callback to the comics.

Due to the way that old comic books were printed some colors (using layers of color put down one at a time) some colors were easier to do than others.

It's why Red and Blue are used so often in super hero costumes, and why the Hulk is green.

Comment: While this answer is lacking in sources, it is most likely the correct answer. Old printing processes were very limited in their color palette for what comic book companies were willing to pay, so a primary color was usually chosen. Often blue was also chosen as a replacement (or highlight) for black. Making heroes blue was not just an artistic choice, but also a financial choice. The movies just adapted what the comics provided 50-80 years ago, including character colors.

Comment: Could you put some sources here to back it up? Then I'll gladly accept.

Comment: That's likely the correct answer, but the way it reads seems to imply we could have a lot of red and green-skinned mutants too. It does not explain the dominance of blue-skinned mutants.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because [Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_(character)) "the first mutant" is blue, when not disguising himself, and he is the ultimate progenitor of many of the mutants in the series who share a similar colouration. He's probably [Mystique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystique_(character))'s father, thus Nightcrawler's Grandfather, and he's been fathering other mutant offspring here and there for millennia.

Comment: Evidence to back this up?

Comment: @PeterNielsen Read the articles in the links.

Comment: @Ash if the link contains relevant evidence you should really edit it into your answer. If it goes down your answer will have no evidence. Better would be to go to the primary source of course.

Comment: While this is a good point, I'd also highlight that comic books traditionally had limited choices of color and white, yellow, pink, brown, and red would end up being not being distinctive enough, green is used for plants and could make a green mutant vanish unless another green ink was used and this left blue as the remaining color.